Cannot make the POST request with my Google Chrome Extension
I have a Google Chrome Extension (GCE) which will request to my server (Nginx - Backend Golang)
I already configured CORS on my backend side, I can easily make any HTTP Methods to my server with Postman or execute CURL in my terminal without getting a CORS issue
The response header will be included in the CORS header below

But for my GCE, I only can make the GET request successfully. For the POST request, I got the issue

Here is my mainfest.json file
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://example.com/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}

my POST function
submitButtonProductCfg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const productName = document.getElementById("product-cfg-name").value;
    const link = backendURL + "/api/extension/v1/products/configs"; 

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        // Prepare data for POST request (modify as needed)
        const data = {
            "name": productName,
        };

        // Create XHR object
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Set up the request
        xhr.open('POST', link);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset = UTF-8");

        // Set up event listeners
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                alert("Success");
            } else {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                alert("Err");
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            alert("Err");
        };

        // Send the request
        try {
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("errr ", e);
        }
    

});
});

I tried Fetch lib also
submitButtonProductCfg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const productName = document.getElementById("product-cfg-name").value;
    const link = backendURL + "/api/extension/v1/products/configs"; // Replace with actual API endpoint

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        // Prepare data for POST request (modify as needed)
        const data = {
            "name": productName,
        };

        fetch(link, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset = UTF-8"
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.text();
                }
            })
            .then(text => {
                alert("Success");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                alert("Error " + error);
            });
    });
});

For the XML request i got the error: Failed to load
For the fetch lib I got the error: Failed to fetch
Please help me!

Are you getting an error message?  You said “I got the issue” followed by a screenshot of some request headers.  Sorry but that doesn’t identify a problem.

hi @James
For the xml request i got the error:  Failed to load,
For the fetch lib I got the error:  Failed to fetch,
That actually an issue I got, that Backend already processed the request and saved the data in my database, but on my GCE seems like it cannot receive the response from the server. The above errors I got from try-catch block. I updated the Fetch function also

Check the console and network tabs of dev tools for more detailed error messages

hi @James thanks for your reply, i checked the console log and network tab, and that's all I have :(. The network tab you can take a look at the 2nd picture, for the error I only see these error messages

"I can easily make any HTTP Methods to my server with Postman or execute CURL in my terminal without getting a CORS issue" - CORS policy is enforced by the browser. No browser, no CORS issues.

post should be POST, it's case-sensitive. Make sure you've reloaded the extension after editing host_permissions and that the hostname matches the one you see in devtools inspector for the request.

Hi @SteffenUllrich and wOxxOm, thank you for the reply. I've found the solution and posted it below.

i tried to move out the fetch request to the outside of Chrome tabs function and add e.preventDefault();
submitButtonProductCfg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const productName = document.getElementById("product-cfg-name").value;
    const link = backendURL + "/api/extension/v1/products/configs"; // Replace with actual API endpoint
    // Prepare data for POST request (modify as needed)
    const data = {
        "name": productName,
    };

    fetch(link, {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            }
        })
        .then(text => {
            alert("Success");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
            alert("Err " + error.value);
        });
});

it works well now, idk the reason anyone can help tell me the root cause.
